# Symfony+JMS Serializer deserialize into existing object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I've been wondering if it's possible to use the JMS Serializer to deserialize JSON into an existing object.

Usually that would be useful for updating an existing object with new data that you have in a JSON format. Symfony's standard deserializer seems to offer that, but I can't seem to find anything about this with JMS. Have to use JMS though if I want the serializedName Annotation option.

The "workaround" is to deserialize and then use Doctrine's EntityManager to merge, but that only works so well, and you can't easily discern which fields are updated if the JSON doesn't contain every single field.

Comment: Where to you see the standard Symfony deserializer offering that ? The JMS is only a more "complete" serializer with heavy features but I doubt it would lack features against the Symfony native one

Comment: The only time I know this is happening is for the User in the current session, but the deserialized data are used to fetch the user from the database so that's using Doctrine so not directly deserialazing "into" an object

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object

Comment: And yeah, seems you can kind of do what I want with JMS, having to put something into the context when you construct it, haven't fully worked it out though.

Answer (score 4):

I have struggled to find the solution but finally found it and here we go:

- your `services.yaml`

```
    jms_serializer.object_constructor:
        alias: jms_serializer.initialized_object_constructor

    jms_serializer.initialized_object_constructor:
        class: App\Service\InitializedObjectConstructor
        arguments: ["@jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor"]
```

- create class `App\Service\InitializedObjectConstructor.php`

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service;

use JMS\Serializer\Construction\ObjectConstructorInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\DeserializationContext;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata;
use JMS\Serializer\Visitor\DeserializationVisitorInterface;

class InitializedObjectConstructor implements ObjectConstructorInterface
{
    private $fallbackConstructor;

    /**
     * @param ObjectConstructorInterface $fallbackConstructor Fallback object constructor
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectConstructorInterface $fallbackConstructor)
    {
        $this->fallbackConstructor = $fallbackConstructor;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function construct(
        DeserializationVisitorInterface $visitor,
        ClassMetadata $metadata,
        $data,
        array $type,
        DeserializationContext $context
    ): ?object {
        if ($context->hasAttribute('target') && 1 === $context->getDepth()) {
            return $context->getAttribute('target');
        }

        return $this->fallbackConstructor->construct($visitor, $metadata, $data, $type, $context);
    }
}
```

- in your controller or your service file

```
        $object = $this->entityManager->find('YourEntityName', $id);

        $context = new DeserializationContext();
        $context->setAttribute('target', $object);

        $data = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), 'YourEntityClassName', 'json', $context);
```

Comment: You're the man! Thank you for this solution. JMS `deserialize` stopped working unexpectedly after the upgrade to the latest version (4.0) and only your solution helped.

Answer (score 1):

So this can be done, I haven't fully worked out how, but I switched away from JMS again, so just for reference, since I guess it's better than keeping the question open for no reason:

https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/79 and you might find more digging around the GitHub too.